# Read meta-data of an existing Lucene index

Tags: lucene, indexing, metadata, analyzer

Is it possible to find out which analyzers/tokenizers were used on a field, by reading an existing Lucene index? If yes, please let me know how. Looking for some kind of meta data that might be stored with the index.

Answer (score 3):

Lucene doesn't store this information. You need to store it by yourself if you want to be able to use it later.

Comment: how does lucene knows that this field is analyzed or stored ?

Comment: Lucene stores some field information, but it is minimal. For instance it knows that a field is indexed, but it doesn't know what type it is (numeric, string?) or what analyzer was used in case of a string.

Comment: interesting, then how does it know while retrieving  result ? (not too fimiliar with how it works)

Comment: Here is the abstraction that Lucene uses for per-field metadata: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/FieldInfo.html

Comment: When it comes to types of stored fields, they are encoded as part of the index for each individual field value. This is why you get a long when you stored a long and a string when you stored a string.